# How does one assure passing a correct object reference to an UI item's click handler at such an item's render time?

Tags: javascript, dom, reference, event-handling, rendering

I need to send 3 parameters to a Javascript function from a dynamically created line item.  but I am having trouble passing them. The first parameter is an object "chatHub" and the other 2 are strings "userName" and connectionId.  Is there anyway to pass these using Template literals?

Here is where the dynamic line items are created:

```
    function getUserNotifications(chatHub) {
    $('#notiContent').empty();
    $.each(connectedUsers, function (index, value) {
        $('#notiContent').append($(`<li onclick="OpenPrivateChatWindow(` + chatHub + ',' +`'${value.UserName}'` +','+ `'${value.ConnectionId}')">Chat With : ${value.UserName}</li>`));
    })
}
```

I need to pass to this function but it is not working:

```
    function OpenPrivateChatWindow(chatHub, userName, connectionId) {

    var ctrId = 'private_' + connectionId;

    if ($('#' + ctrId).length > 0) return;
    $("#ViewChatModal").modal({});
   $('#btnSendMessage').click(function () {

    var msg = $('#txtPrivateMessage').val()
        if (msg.length > 0) {

            chatHub.server.sendPrivateMessage(connectionId, userName, msg);
             
        }
    })
```

Comment: `chatHub` obviously needs to be an object. But with the inline event handling one does loose this information. Use `addEventListener` for initializing the event handling of each notification item.

Comment: Not necessarily. Perhaps he is passing the object as JSON.

Comment: @WaisKamal ... any JSON based method in this case is of no use since in the end an object reference is needed by the `OpenPrivateChatWindow` function.

Comment: Since the OP's code seems to be *jQuery* based the OP also might consider making use of this libraries [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method for each of a `#notiContent`'s list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function registerUserNotifications(chatHub) {

  const rootNode = $('#notiContent');
  rootNode.empty();

  $.each(connectedUsers, function (index, value) {

    const connectionId = value.ConnectionId;
    const userName = value.UserName;
    const listItem = $(`<li>Chat With : ${ userName }</li>`);

    listItem.on( "click", function(/*evt*/) {
      OpenPrivateChatWindow(chatHub, userName, connectionId);
    });

    rootNode.append(listItem);
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it did not work.  User names do not show in the list and nothing happens on the click. I did not downvote your response because I would never penalize someone for trying to help me.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff ... there was a line missing ... `rootNode.append(listItem);` ... maybe this was also the reason for gotten downvoted. So, please give it another try.

Comment: it worked once I added your edit, I just don't understand why it worked, but thank you very much.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff ... after creating `listItem` and registering the event on it such an item of cause has still to be added to its parent node.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an object that way but what you can do is create the li element, add a listener to that which you will pass your function to. Below is a quick example of this.

Where you are currently passing the literal etc, don't. Create a new element with that and then add an event watcher to that watching for a click.

```
let liElement = $(`<li>Chat with ${value.UserName}</li>`);
$('#notiContent').append(liElement)
liElement.on('click', () => { OpenPrivateChatWindow(ChatHub, variable... ) })
```

Comment: Ah you're right, I forgot to wrap in an anonymous boi. Thanks